# expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected) jest enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a following test to see if the state is set.

```
    const setState = jest.fn();
    const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');

    useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState]);

    it('should update state upon changing department in select field', () => {
        const select = wrapper.find('select');
        select.instance().value = 'Customer Success';
        select.simulate('change');
        expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Customer Success');
    });
```

I set the state with following code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { postJobAction } from './redux/postJobActions';

const PostJobComponent = () => {
  const [department, setDepartment] = useState('');


const onPostJobSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    dispatch(postJobAction({
      department,
    }));
  };

  const onDepartmentChange = (event) => {
    setDepartment(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className='post-job'>
      <form onSubmit={onPostJobSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Department</label>
          <select className='job__department' required onChange={onDepartmentChange}>
            <option value=''>Select</option>
            <option value='Customer Success'>Customer Success</option>
            <option value='Professional Services'>Professional Services</option>
            <option value='Service Support'>Service And Support</option>
            <option value='Engineering'>Engineering</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostJobComponent;
```

As you can see I am calling `onDepartmentChange` function on `select`. It works perfectly fine in code however, when I run test it shows this error.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "Customer Success"

    Number of calls: 0

      69 |      select.instance().value = 'Customer Success';
      70 |      select.simulate('change');
    > 71 |      expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Customer Success');
         |                       ^
      72 |  });
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: I would strongly recommend _not_ mocking React's API, you don't own that. Test the _behaviour_ - how's that `department` state actually going to get _used_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated my code. It is used in `onPostJobSubmit` function and sent via dispatch action to the server. How can I test this bahviour?

Comment: Have a look at https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests - I'd agree with their recommendation to test that in an integration style wherever possible.